# Not able to upload Video File using blobUrl

Tags: javascript, file-upload, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload video using blobUrl, but it is not getting uploaded properly and always giving file size 64 bytes. Following is the code I have written.

```
onFilesSelected(evt) {
   const file = evt.target.files[0];

   const videoBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);

   fileObject = new File([videoBlobUrl], file.name, { type: file.type });

   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', fileObject);
   formData.append('type', 'video');

   // Send `formData` to API
}
```

Can anyone please help me, what I'm doing wrong.

P.S.: I am not using `FileReader` API, because for large files it's too slow to show the preview.